# 'create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to set up react app using create-react-app command on windows pc. I already used it on my mac computer, and it works well. But I encounter a problem. Here my steps on command line. Am i missing something?

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Users\ugur\Desktop\deneme

C:\Users\ugur\Desktop\deneme>npm init


This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See 'npm help json' for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use 'npm install <pkg> --save' afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (deneme)
version: (1.0.0)
description:
entry point: (index.js)
test command:
git repository:
keywords:
license: (ISC)
About to write to C:\Users\ugur\Desktop\deneme\package.json:

{
   "name": "deneme",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
   "author": "Ugur <ugur@abc.com.tr> (http://www.abc.com.tr)",
   "license": "ISC"
}


Is this ok? (yes)

C:\Users\ugur\Desktop\deneme>npm install -g create-react-app
C:\Users\ugur\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\ugur\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
C:\Users\ugur\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- create-react-app@0.2.0
  +-- chalk@1.1.3
  | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1
  | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
  | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0
  | | `-- ansi-regex@2.0.0
  | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
  | `-- supports-color@2.0.0
  +-- cross-spawn@4.0.0
  | +-- lru-cache@4.0.1
  | | +-- pseudomap@1.0.2
  | | `-- yallist@2.0.0
  | `-- which@1.2.10
  |   `-- isexe@1.1.2
  +-- minimist@1.2.0
  `-- semver@5.3.0


C:\Users\ugur\Desktop\deneme>create-react-app new_app

'create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Also npm configuration path is like

C:\Users\ugur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `C:\Users\ugur\AppData\Roaming\npm` to windows PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks, I found it's already in my PATH,but I still get the same error. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: @dli, can you ensure you change your own username in the path which Uğur mentioned? And you closed and reopened command window? I am using Windows 10 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Might sound dumb, but after adding the above to my Window PATH variable, I found it helpful to close all terminals that I was trying to execute this command on and reopened them. Resetting the terminal session isn't enough.

Comment: When you add a variable to the PATH, it is indeed recommended to close all terminals and also sign out from your Windows session (or reboot).

Comment: I need to add one note one , After update the path variable , close CMD and open it again print path variable first to make sure it's updated
Then call the command again 'create-react-app' that is working with me!

Comment: And one thing to note is that the path should be added to the "System variables" and not the "User variables". At least that's what solved my issue!

Comment: And one thing to note is that the path should be added to the "System variables" and not the "User variables". At least that's what solved my issue!

Answer (score 136):

Try with this `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: Giving you an up-vote because technically this was the correct answer, at least for me. (This worked perfectly).

Comment: Perfect solution. Worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: u should install create reat app command globally like 
>npm install -g create-react-app

Comment: Since I'm going through tutorials to learn react I don't want to have to do the npx every time. I used @Ashish Bansal solution and then create-react-app worked

Answer (score 18):

simply putting 'npx' in front of the command will solve this if you are running older version of node.

try this and it will work fine.

npx create-react-app [yourProjectName]

Answer (score 11):

I'm adding this because this pops up on Google and I was having trouble.

I'm on Windows 10 and I searched for 'create-react-app' in `C:\` and the path was `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`.

I added that to the Environment Variables > Path and the command works now.

Comment: there is no folder inside \npm

Answer (score 10):

Use `npx create-react-app my-app`. This will solve any issue with the system path variable.

React GitHub documentation suggests this as well. 
Read [Here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Answer (score 8):

First Check your Node version. if your node version is 8 or greater then 8 then 
use
**'npx create-react-app my-app'**

In the above version we need to change only one word that is npx

You don't need to do another things. 
I hope this will help you

Answer (score 6):

**Another one that might work is to use Powershell and type:**

```
npx create-react-app new_app --use-npm
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue despite having

```
npm install create-react-app --global
```

Later tried

```
npm init react-app projectname
```

This worked for me and it created a React project.
Also this worked

```
npx create-react-app projectname
```

Answer (score 3):

I also get same problem but I resolve it by following steps

1. Check your global directory by using command **npm root -g**
2. check the folder, will it have **.cmd** of your installed packages.
3. If yes, Please copy the path of folder and put in path of user variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

just do this:

> npm i npx
> then
> npx create-react-app <app-name

Answer (score 2):

I had to add c:\node_modules.bin to my path to run create-react-app

Do a search for create-react-app and use that in your path.

Comment: searched for it but did not find it anywhere

Answer (score 2):

- Run : `npx install create-react-app nameOfYourFolder` instead of `npm
  install create-react-app nameOfYourFolder` (npx comes with npm 5.2+
  and higher)
- Then : `cd nameOfYourFolder`
- Then run : `npm start`

You can find more in React documentation [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/README.md#getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue is mainly caused by two reasons:

1. Path variable issue
2. Npm version issue

Add C:\Users\ugur\AppData\Roaming\npm to Windows PATH variable and upgrade npm version to 5.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Do the following from `TERMINAL`:

- `cd myReactApp`
- `npx create-react-app .`

This should work!

Answer (score 1):

This is a windows variable path problem, i have faced the same problem recently, the following are possible root cause of the problem , installing node via nvm(node version manager) so to solve the issue in this case you after running `npm install -g create-react-app` got to the location in my case `C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm` in the copy create-react-app to `C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.18.3` and also move the folder in node_module folder called create-react-app to the specific version you are using under nvm , after that you should be able to use create-react-app without and issue. i hope this will help someone

Answer (score 1):

User following command

npx create-react-app my-app

Answer (score 1):

Adding npx to the command solves the problem and react app is created
e.g:

```
$ npx create-react-app my-react-app
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by following steps

1. npm install -g create-react-app
   To install react app globally
2. create-react-app version
   To check if it is installed and if its installed then what's the version.
3. create-react-app [name]
4. cd [name]
5. npm start

Comment: This will install a deprecated version

Answer (score 0):

By installing react globally this error can be solved for those who didn't get even after the environmental variable is set.   `npm i -g create-react-app`    . Now the modules will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

If above solution not working try this on it will work 100%

0)first of all install package "npm create-create-app -g" or "yarn add create-react-app" then

1)open cmd and type "npm root -g" this command will give you path of node_model directory for global packages

2) copy that path only upto npm directory eg.C:\Users\vchaudhari\AppData\Roaming\npm

3) open environmental variables in windows and pest that command in that save it .

4) close current cmd and open new cmd and use command "create-react-app demoapp"

5) Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Environment
node -v: v8.9.3
npm -v:4.6.1
yarn --version (if you use Yarn):
npm ls react-scripts (if you haven’t ejected): C:\Users\chacker\my-react-app>npm ls react-scripts
my-react-app@1.0.0 C:\Users\chacker\my-react-app
`-- (empty)
Then, specify:

Operating system: windows 7
Browser and version (if relevant):
Steps to Reproduce
(Write your steps here:)

npm install -g create-react-app
log->
C:\Users\chacker\my-react-app>npm install -g create-react-app
C:\Users\chacker\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\chacker\AppData\R
aming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
C:\Users\chacker\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- create-react-app@1.4.3
create-react-app my-app

Answer (score 0):

For me just `create-react-app project-name` worked after adding path `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` to my environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using **Node.js command prompt** as an administrator

Answer (score 0):

Someone who is still having this issue, Go to C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm- check if .cmd is create-react- app or creact-react-native-app.

Mine was the latter.

Also, make sure you don't have two different version installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create an app on my PC with Windows PowerShell. I tried updating and setting up environment variables accordingly. But nothing worked for me until I followed these steps.

1. npm install create-react-app
2. npx create-react-app

and then it started working. Use these commands in the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, seems the create react app has version issue, adding @latest solves it, installing it in local is by no means useful as the use of npx is to get latest version from remote repository that from local.

```
npx create-react-app@latest react-webdev-course
```

Answer (score 0):

documentation says: `npm init react-app my-app`

reference: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

> npm uninstall -g create-react-app

or

> yarn global remove create-react-app

it will solve issue

Answer (score 0):

issue: may be you miss somethings library or dependency solution: npm i react-app-env

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my Windows Account name. I changed like this
`Hüseyin Baduk -> huseyinbaduk`. But you need to be careful this change process corrupt your other applications use user data in C:/Users/%/

Answer (score 0):

##### I wanted to create a react app with a typescript template. Posting this as a reference for anyone interested in achieving the above.
I am using node v21.4.0

The below steps worked for me :

1. Install create-react-app globally via the following command.

   `npm install -g create-react-app`
2. then enter `create-react-app` command with `--template` flag set to `typescript` with your app name.

   `create-react-app <your-app-name> --template typescript`

Happy coding...

Answer (score -2):

I solved problem by following below steps

1) open Node.js command prompt

2) Then type "npm install create-react-app -g" (g for global access) command to install create-react-app

3) Then type "npm install create-react-native-app -g" (g for global access) command to install create-react-native-app

Follow step #2 for use create-react-app

Follow step #3 only if you want to use create-react-native-app otherwise its optional.

Answer (score -2):

I **reinstalled node.js** and added the path given by **npm root -g** command to my path variable to get it working.