# Error of recognizing create-react-app also i installed it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, command-prompt

why also I installed  create-react-app correctly 
then when I try to create my-app this message appear

'create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

https://prnt.sc/psyvzp

thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Are you sure that the directory that npm saves the commands in is on your PATH? Also, please make this a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977255/create-react-app-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 0):

This work like magic

`npx create-react-app my-app`