# create-react-app not recognizable as internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, git-bash

I am using `Git Bash` terminal on my Windows 10 machine. I have below versions of `node` and `npm`

```
$ node -v
v12.16.1

$ npm -v
6.13.4
```

However while running the command  `$ npx create-react-app my-app` I am getting the below error

```
'create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have added the `create-react-app` location till `npm` in `PATH` variable and checked its present using the `echo` command.

Also I am able to run the above npx command in `cmd` but not in `Git Bash`. Is there anything different I have to do run it?

```
PATH : /c/Users/SAURABH/AppData/Roaming/npm
```

I am able to run the create-react-app by doing the below though:

```
C:/Users/SAURABH/AppData/Roaming/npm/create-react-app one-hello-world
```

Not sure why `npx` is not working

EDIT: I solved by adding the below to PATH

```
C:\Users\SAURABH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

But the above path has the create-react-app folder and not the batch file. It should point to some batch file right?

Comment: Does this issue answer your question? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3594

Comment: @No, it states add the location of create-react-app in the PATH variable which I already have

Comment: have you tried some stuff mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977255/create-react-app-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: @gdh, yes tried all of them. in cmd it running but not in GIT BASH. Might have something to do with GIT BASH?

Comment: i see -- try closing your git bash and open it as an administrator ... then try to uninstal your create-react-app and install again it globally..

Comment: You can use `git` in cmd, why you're using `git bash`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same issue on my mac, start using yarn create react-app my-app . This solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this command with cmd or PowerShell. it's a bug with GitBash.
I can solve this error with cmd.