# i want to install npx create react app in react js but it is not installing? I have installed Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

I used npx create-react-app my-app  but it says

> 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not
> recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> batch file. spawn
> C:\Users\rishi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts ENOENT

I have set the environment variables but still happening. Please help.

[image]

Comment: This link may help u
['create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977255/create-react-app-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: did you installed android SDK?

Comment: try this command `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`

Comment: i saw it but it does not work for me

Comment: if you are using vs-code as your editor then install git then try to install using vs-code git terminal

Comment: or you can try git terminal to

Comment: the same error is coing :- 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
spawn C:\Users\rishi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts ENOENT

Comment: but what does this error mean