# This is first time I am trying to set up react app on windows. But I encounter a problem. Am i doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, terminal

as i searched i used this command: `npx create-react-app my-react-app`  and here what i got:

[image]

it says **Need to install the following packages: `create-react-app@5.0.1`**

so, i used the command `create-react-app@5.0.1`  and the result is:

[image]

because of this problem i can not have a react environment. How can i fix this?

editttt
for the guy who says just click (Y) for the first picture i already did that many times and it does not work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKAVV.png)

Comment: Didn't you forget to put `npx` in front of `create-react-app@5.0.1` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977255/create-react-app-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 3):

npx will already do it for you. It just tells you that it will need to install that package and asks whether it's OK to proceed. You just need to answer <kbd>y</kbd> (yes).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Vite instead of create-react-app, https://vitejs.dev/guide/.

Answer (score -1):

To install the package you should write the following `npm install -g create-react-app@latest` and when asked input "Y"

Then you should create a react app with `npx create-react-app nameoftheapp`

Update 1:

as pointed out from CherryDT, it is suggested to add the global flag in the installation

Update 2:

Also have you tried to reopen the terminal?

Comment: npx: The OP is already doing that. And for the install: it's useless to install it in the parent folder and it's not even needed because npx does it for you.